# How to choose $\lambda (x) =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}x \alpha}{\alpha^{2}} d\mu (\alpha)$; so $\lambda ^{-1}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, fourier-analysis, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis

We define,

$$\lambda (x) =\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^{2}x \alpha}{\alpha^{2}} d\mu (\alpha),  (\mu(0)=0) $$
where $\mu (\alpha)$ is a non-decreasing function such that the integral converges for every real $x$. Some authors call $\lambda (x)$ a ***negative definite function***. (This is proved by von Neumann, J.; Schoenberg, I. J. in 1941; see, [Fourier integrals and metric geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=Fourier%20integrals%20and%20metric%20geometry&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq))

But here I am interested to learn some method(techniques) (if exists) to know about  behaviour of the function $\lambda(x)$.

> **My Question**: (1) How to choose a non-decreasing function $\mu (\alpha)$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{\lambda(x)} dx < \infty.$ ? 
>   (2) Suppose given $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$; which is also continuous on $\mathbb R$ and vanishing at infinity. Can we expect to choose $\mu(\alpha)$ (may be in terms of $f$) so that $\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)| \lambda (x) + \frac{1}{\lambda (x)} dx < \infty $ ? If not, can we produce some counter example ?

(I am also looking for any references or suggestions concerning this; are well come)

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure of $\lambda^{-1} $?

Comment: Prof. MB; I think, I am sure; and the motivation behind this integrals, is that, it is a tools to study, contraction in the space $A=\{f\in L^{1}: \hat{f}\in L^{1} \}.$ for detail, you may see the [theorem-III](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02395018); thanks a lot;